# How to parse and stack XML nodes and children correctly?

Tags: python, pandas, xml, parsing

I am currently trying to analyze some voting behavior in the European Parliament, using the parliaments XML interface. However, even though I am able to import the information and manipulate them somehow, I am not able to a meaningful pandas DataFrame.

E.g. I try to set up two data frame with "for" and "against" votes. However, both data frame yield the same size and the same order...Can someone please help?

Thanks!

```
import lxml
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from itertools import product, chain
from urllib.request import urlopen

import io

var_url = urlopen('https://www.europarl.europa.eu/doceo/document/PV-9-2020-12-18-RCV_FR.xml')
xmldoc = ET.parse(var_url)
xmlroot = xmldoc.getroot()

vote_items = []
all_vote_items = []
for avote in xmlroot.iter('RollCallVote.Result'):
    vote_Nr = avote.attrib.get('Identifier')
    for anitem in avote.iter('Result.For'):
            for amep in avote.iter('PoliticalGroup.Member.Name'):
                mep_id = amep.get('MepId')
                vote_items = [vote_Nr, mep_id]
                all_vote_items.append(vote_items)
for_meps = pd.DataFrame(all_vote_items,columns=['VOTE_NUMBER','vmep_id'])      


vote_items = []
all_vote_items = []
for avote in xmlroot.iter('RollCallVote.Result'):
    vote_Nr = avote.attrib.get('Identifier')
    for anitem in avote.iter('Result.Against'):
            for amep in avote.iter('PoliticalGroup.Member.Name'):
                mep_id = amep.get('MepId')
                vote_items = [vote_Nr, mep_id]
                all_vote_items.append(vote_items)
against_meps = pd.DataFrame(all_vote_items,columns=['VOTE_NUMBER','vmep_id'])
```

UPDATE:

I tried now to combine all three, however fall back to a (39,4) data frame. How can I stack correctly?

````
vote_items = []
all_vote_items = []

for avote in xmlroot.iter('RollCallVote.Result'):
    vote_Nr = avote.attrib.get('Identifier')
    
    for anitem in avote.iter('Result.For'):
        for agroup in anitem.iter('Result.PoliticalGroup.List'):
            for amep in agroup.iter('PoliticalGroup.Member.Name'):
                mep_id_for = amep.get('MepId')
    
    for anitem in avote.iter('Result.Against'):
        for agroup in anitem.iter('Result.PoliticalGroup.List'):
            for amep in agroup.iter('PoliticalGroup.Member.Name'):
                mep_id_against = amep.get('MepId')
                
    for anitem in avote.iter('Result.Abstention'):
        for agroup in anitem.iter('Result.PoliticalGroup.List'):
            for amep in agroup.iter('PoliticalGroup.Member.Name'):
                mep_id_abstention = amep.get('MepId')
    
    
    vote_items = [vote_Nr, mep_id_for, mep_id_against, mep_id_abstention]
    all_vote_items.append(vote_items)
            
all_meps = pd.DataFrame(all_vote_items,columns=['vote_nr','vote_for','vote_against','vote_abstention'])```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there's a bug in your code on this line:

```
for amep in avote.iter('PoliticalGroup.Member.Name'):
```

You should probably iterate over `anitem` objects instead of `avote`. There are two places where you need to fix it. I've just checked and this results in different `all_vote_items` lists.

Comment: Indeed, that was it. Thank you very much! Other question: Do you know how I can combine to get all three types (for, against, abstention) in one DataFrame?

If I do something like in the update above, I just get again a dataframe of (39,4) but not "stacked"